# cannot open file on qt6.5 for andriod

Tags: android, c++, qt6, qfile

there  is a already exist file name u1.txt   but  cannot  open it  ,
code :  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqdPt.png)

log like that: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X59z.png)

already has prommission  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imKni.png)

```
void MainWindow::on_test_2_clicked()
{

    QFile wenjian("/storage/emulated/0/10/u1.txt");
    bool ok = wenjian.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    qDebug() <<ok;

    bool exist = QFile::exists("/storage/emulated/0/10/u1.txt");
    qDebug() <<exist;
}
```

Comment: Please Copy-paste code and results as text into your questions: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)